# Refreshing page (f5) causes my api to return JSON and display plain JSON

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

Using React and Flask.
Created a website, python fetches data from 3rd party api(s), then displays on page.

I am having a problem with one of my renders, the first time the page loads, the API returns json and that json gets rendered correctly with my elements.
If I press f5, the page refreshes, the API gets called again (I can see fresh data being retrieved) but the data just gets put on the screen as plain json, not being rendered in my elements.

chooseStash.js

```
      const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const selectedStashIds = [];
      sortedGroupKeys.forEach((key) => {
        const stashes = groupedStashes[key];
        stashes.forEach((stash) => {
          if (document.getElementById(stash.id).checked) {
            selectedStashIds.push(stash.id);
          }
        });
      });
    
      const response = await fetch('/stashIDs', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ stashIDs: selectedStashIds }),
      });
    
      if (response.ok) {
        history.push('/DisplayItems');
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to store stash IDs:', response.statusText);
      }
    };
```

Here the user makes a selection on the page and hits a submit button, this sends some data to my flask file

api in my flask file that gets data sent to, and stored with StashIDs = data.get('stashIDs')

```
@app.route('/stashIDs', methods=['POST'])
def storeStashIDs():
    '''
    Stores the user selected stash IDs in a session variable
    This is used to pull the stash content in the next endpoint
    '''
    data = request.get_json()
    logger.info(f'[data = request.get_json()] : {data}')
    stashIDs = data.get('stashIDs')
    session['stashIDs'] = stashIDs
    logger.info(f'[StashIDs] : {stashIDs}')
    return 'Data received store stash id', 200
```

When the user hits submit and teh data gets sent to flask, we are redirected to /DisplayItems

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStashContent = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/DisplayItems');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("Fetched data:", data);
      const items = processStashContentData(data);
      console.log("Setting items:", items);
      setItems(items);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchStashContent();
  }, []);
```

Which, the first time the user gets directed to this page, /DisplayItems API (below) gets called and pulls back a bunch of data that is then rendered accordingly...

```
@app.route('/DisplayItems', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def returnStashContent():
    '''
    Returns the stash content to the frontend
    '''
    headers = session.get('headers')
    league = session.get('league')  
    stashIDs = session.get('stashIDs')
    logger.info(f'[stashIDs] : {stashIDs}')
    stashContent = initializeGetData.pullStashData(userSelectedStashList=stashIDs,poeLeague=league,headers=headers)
    return jsonify({'stashContent':stashContent})
```

However, when I press f5 on this screen, I can see a fresh API call happens, the data is then sent to the screen without being rendered through my elements, also, none of the console.logs trigger from the useEffect

Any assistance / guidance would be apprecaited in helping me understand whats going on

I have added logging in the api, and can see it is being called
I have added logging in js and can see it is not being called when I press f5 (but is the first time the user goes to the page)

I have tried playing around with the useEffect, but I am not making any progress

```js
return (
                <div
                  className={`item-card ${itemType[item.frameType]}`}
                  key={item.id}
                >
                  <div className={`card-title ${itemType[item.frameType]}`}>
                    {item.baseType.includes("Flask")
                      ? item.typeLine
                      : `${item.name} ${item.typeLine}`}{" "}
                  </div>
                  <div className="item-content">
                    <div className="item-icon">
                      <img src={item.icon} alt={item.baseType} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="item-info-container">
                      <div className="item-info item-stats-font">
                        {item.frameType !== 4 &&
                          item.frameType !== 5 &&
                          item.frameType !== 6 && (
                            <>
                              <ul className="level">Item Level: {item.ilvl}</ul>
                              {item.ilvl && (
                                <div
                                  className={`separator ${
                                    itemType[item.frameType]
                                  } ilvl`}
                                ></div>
                              )}{" "}
                            </>
                          )}

                          {item.baseType.includes("Cluster Jewel") && (
                            <>
                              <ul className="enchantMods">
                                {item.enchantMods &&
                                  item.enchantMods.map((mod) => (
                                    <li key={mod}>{mod}</li>
                                  ))}
                              </ul>
                              <div
                                className={`separator ${
                                  itemType[item.frameType]
                                }`}
                              ></div>
                            </>
                          )}                          
                        <ul className="properties">
                          {processedProperties.map((property) => (
                            <li key={property.name}>{property.displayValue}</li>
                          ))}{" "}
                        </ul>
                        {processedProperties.length > 0 && (
                          <div
                            className={`separator ${
                              itemType[item.frameType]
                            }`}
                          ></div>
                        )}
                        <div className="requirements">
                          {item.requirements && (
                            <span>
                              Requires:{" "}
                              {item.requirements
                                .map(
                                  (requirement) =>
                                    `${
                                      requirement.name
                                    } ${requirement.values.map((v) => v[0])}`
                                )
                                .join(", ")}{" "}
                            </span>
                          )}{" "}
                        </div>

                        {item.requirements && (
                          <div
                            className={`separator ${itemType[item.frameType]}`}
                          ></div>
                        )}
                        <ul className="implicitMods">
                          {item.implicitMods &&
                            item.implicitMods.map((mod) => (
                              <li key={mod}>{mod}</li>
                            ))}{" "}
                        </ul>

                        {item.implicitMods && (
                          <div
                            className={`separator ${itemType[item.frameType]}`}
                          ></div>
                        )}
                        {item.frameType !== 6 && (
                          <ul className="explicitMods">
                            {item.explicitMods &&
                              item.explicitMods.map((mod) => (
                                <li key={mod}>{mod}</li>
                              ))}{" "}
                          </ul>
                        )}
                        {item.explicitMods && item.frameType !== 6 && (
                          <div
                            className={`separator ${
                              itemType[item.frameType]
                            } explici`}
                          ></div>
                        )}

                        {item.frameType === 4 &&
                          item.hybrid &&
                          item.hybrid.isVaalGem && (
                            <>
                              <div
                                className={`separator ${
                                  itemType[item.frameType]
                                }`}
                              ></div>
                              <ul className="hybrid-properties">
                                {item.hybrid.properties &&
                                  item.hybrid.properties.map((property) => (
                                    <li key={property.name}>
                                      {property.displayMode === 3
                                        ? property.name.replace(
                                            "{0}",
                                            property.values[0][0]
                                          )
                                        : `${
                                            property.name
                                          }: ${property.values.map(
                                            (v) => v[0]
                                          )}`}{" "}
                                    </li>
                                  ))}{" "}
                              </ul>
                              <div
                                className={`separator ${
                                  itemType[item.frameType]
                                }`}
                              ></div>
                              <ul className="hybrid-explicitMods">
                                {item.hybrid.explicitMods &&
                                  item.hybrid.explicitMods.map((mod) => (
                                    <li key={mod}>{mod}</li>
                                  ))}{" "}
                              </ul>
                            </>
                          )}
                        {!item.identified && (
                          <div className="unidentified">Unidentified</div>
                        )}
                        {item.corrupted && (
                          <div className="corrupted">Corrupted</div>
                        )}
                        <div className="influences">
                          {item.influences &&
                            Object.keys(item.influences)
                              .filter((influence) => item.influences[influence])
                              .map((influence, index) => (
                                <div
                                  key={index}
                                  className={`influence-${influence}`}
                                >
                                  {capitalizeFirstLetter(influence)}{" "}
                                </div>
                              ))}{" "}
                        </div>
                        <div className="stash-name">
                          Stash: {item.stashName}{" "}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
```

Code where handleSubmit is called

```
<Form className="mainStashBox" method="POST" style={{ width: '100%', height: '80%' }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML I feel like your code snippets aren't in a good order for me to read and understand your code or there are just pieces missing

Comment: At a guess, you've written an SPA, and haven't configured the server correctly. The big hint is that you've shown the code for a function called "handleSubmit" which is unlikely to be executed on a page load.

Comment: @Wayne 

Hey, I have added the code that is used to render the items to the post - apologies, there are many pieces of code within this project, I appreciate it probably isnt the best approach, but I only put what I thought was relevant (obviously could be wrong as im still running into problems ^^)

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey! I added the snippet where handleSubmit is called - the user clicks a button, which calls that function and sends the form data to server

Comment: `the user clicks a button ....` - which does not happen on a page load, so it's not relevant

Comment: I think you should really try to simplify this question

Comment: @JaromandaX okay, apologies, but im not following - I appreciate that that may not be correct. But Im saying, when the use clicks hte button they do get redirected, and the page renders with the correct information on /DisplayItems - when they hit f5 on /DisplayItems the API is called - but the elements dont render that time

Comment: @Wayne Hey, apologies I am not following where the issue is here. My problem is when I press F5, the elements do not render on /DisplayItems .... The first time the user visits this page, the elements DO render

Comment: Is this an SPA you're writing? If so, then the most likely issue is a poorly configured http server

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, this is single page - Is there any thing else I could provide that would help debug? my thoughts were the useEffect that calls fetchStashContent is the issue - it works then the page loads the first time, but on f5 it dosnt call, thus no call to the api - but the api is getting called which im guessing is due to the information stored on the server and calling /displayitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve it...

As the url for this page was /DisplayItems and the api endpoint was also /DisplayItems, it seems like this was causing some issue...